# Where can I find the distance slider on careers?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I've entered a search, and I'm trying to adjust the distance slider. Unforunately I can't find the slider, nor can I manually adjust.

[image]

I'm on Chrome Version <strike>24.0.1312.56 m</strike> 24.0.1312.57 m

Comment: Did you paste "moncton, nb" right into the "where" box? The slider appears as soon as you start typing in there, apparently not if you just paste into it (on Chrome 24.0.1312.52)

Comment: No, i was typing it.

Comment: Yes, the same happens for me. I'm also using Chrome 24.0.1312.57 (on OS X 10.6.8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem in addition to the one in @mjibson’s answer – after submitting a search, it would disappear. This should be resolved now.

Answer (score 3):

This was indeed a bug (the slider would in rare situations fail to load), but it was fixed 5 days ago. If you continue to see it, tell us if there's an error in your javascript console.

Comment: I've taken a look today. If I do a search and press `enter` or the `search` button, the slider is gone, If it reload the page with the search in the query string, the slider comes back. Press search and the slider disappears again.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce.

[image]

I see the slider on Chrome 24.0.1312.57 m on Windows 8 regardless of whether I type in or paste in the text.

[image]

Check to ensure that you don't have JavaScript disabled, interfering ad blockers, or corrupted cache or cookies.

Comment: I *can* reproduce it. It happens after you click search (or hit Enter). As you can see from his print screen the slider completely disappears. It's not just inactive like in your printscreen.